# LaravelCollective - Form Model Binding and custom attribute

Tags: laravel, laravelcollective

With LaravelCollective, we can populate a form like this :

```
{{ Form::model($user, ['route' => ['user.update', $user->id]]) }}
```

If we declare an input like this (inside a view) :

```
{{ Form::text('name') }}
```

the field will be automatically filled by the attribute "$user->name".

However, if we want to add some custom parameters (like class) :

```
{{ Form::text('name', ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

we have the following error :
`htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`,
OK so framework is waiting for the second parameter...

```
{{ Form::text('name', '',  ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

But in that case, we lose the "auto-populate" feature.
Is there a solution to custom form fields, and keeping the auto populate functionality ?

Thanks !

Comment: Add null value as second parameter instead an empty string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution given by porloscerros :

```
{{ Form::text('name', NULL,  ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```